# How to refer an object within itself in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I am having the following JavaScript object:

`var Fruit = {
    Apple:{ Color: "Red" },
    Banana:{ Color: "Yellow" },
    Lemon:{ Color: "Yellow" }
}`

How can I refer `Fruit.Lemon.Color` to `Fruit.Banana.Color` ?

I've tried this

`Lemon:{ Color: Fruit.Banana.Color }`

but not work...

Lastly, I use the following method:

`var Fruit = {
    Apple:{ Color: "Red" },
    Banana:{ Color: "Yellow" }
}
Fruit.Lemon = { Color: Fruit.Banana.Color }`

It works fine, but I want to keep all objects inside one scope of codes, no extra lines.

Comment: I don;t think you can because the object `Fruit` is not defined yet (you are still defining it).

Comment: use `Fruit.Lemon.Color = Fruit.Banana.Color` instead of `Lemon:{ Color: Fruit.Banana.Color }`

Comment: @balexandre that is what OP is trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: darn... my bad then!